# Chromium won't run at all

Tags: pi-2, chromium

I installed chromium on my raspberry pi 2 with

```
sudo get-apt install chromium-browser
```

It went through the installation process and made a shortcut in the star menu. BUT whenever I click the shortcut nothing happen.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try opening it from the command line `chromium-browser` as will output an error of what is wrong.

Comment: Chromium browser is better be compiled from sources - as my experience showed me that in different repositories it's an old versions and/or some library conflicts are happening. But if I just update the source and compile it on place - it works like a charm and with a newer version